# Custom alternative to Datasheet view of SharePoint

Tags: custom, datasheet

I have taxonomy fields as well as rich text boxes in my SharePoint 2010 list which needs to be edited in datasheet view so that bulk update is possible. Also I have Workflow goin on that list so Content Aprroval is On , I want to initiate manual workflow on each item when needed.

I could not find destination via Data sheet view of SharePoint.

Is there any workaround to it , I mean if we can have any custom thing created which could solve the problem , or is there any software which could be loaded to get list items in Datasheet mode and could be edited too.

Regards,

Prakriti

Answer (score 1):

I've used and modified Batch Edit from codeplex before for similar requirements and had great results.

http://sp2010batchedit.codeplex.com/